# Array copying using dynamic variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

I have an array of 24 elements stored under the array **mba_ext**.

`echo ${mba_ext[13]} gives me expected results.`

Now I have created a variable `temp="mba_ext"`

Now I am trying to copy contents of the array to another array by making use of temp variable. I wrote the code as shown below:

`new_array=$(eval echo '$'{${temp}[@]})`

When I give `echo$new_array` I am getting all contents of array getting printed without any index.

When I give `echo ${new_array[4]}` I am getting no results. Ideally this command should print the content at index location 4.

Can some please help?

Comment: Why is `eval` being used? also you have not used any array by doing `temp="mba_ext"`

Comment: What if I want to pass mba_ext as a variable and not directly?  temp is a variable that should hold name of the array and not the array itself. And I want to pass the variable name to code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/1397146/432690).

> You can use variable indirection with a proper array […]. The tricky thing is that you have to include the array element (or `[@]` for all elements) in the variable you're indirecting through.

Example code with the names you used:

```
mba_ext=('normal' 'with space' 'double"quote' "single'quote" $'new-\n-line' '\backslash')
temp="mba_ext"
temparray="${temp}[@]"   # This includes the array name AND "[@]"
new_array=("${!temparray}")
printf '<%s>\n' "${new_array[@]}"
```

Comment: The `temp` variable is an unnecessary step, but the `!` part is key here.

Comment: The above solution works perfectly fine. Now I have one small query on top of that. Assume I am declaring variable x as temp_array. i.e.,



`x="temp_array"`

So as per the answer given above i am expecting something like below to be shown

`$x="${temp[@]}"`

But its throwing error. 

Could you please help me with the error?

Comment: `declare arrayClone=("${temparray[@]}")` --> Works fine

`declare $type=("${temparray[@]}")` --> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Note: variable type="arrayClone"

Can you help me how can i rectify the second line of code

@kamil-maciorowski